# Type/properties of Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

```
var prototypeType = typeof Object.prototype
console.log(prototypeType);

var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty");
console.log(hasOwn);
```

Why is nothing printed to the console with this code? Should it? If it shouldn't print anything, a brief explanation as to why would be appreciated.

Note: this is part of a Codecademy course which is explaining how plain objects inherit from Object.prototype, but surely if Object.prototype contains nothing to inherit then it's pointless?

Edit: I think there must just be a bug with Codecademy after being told what it should print.

Comment: Where you tried out this code?it will print object and true

Comment: It should returns **object** then **true**

Comment: It's on Codecademy, when I try printing it nothing comes up. However it offers for me to continue? Anyway thanks for saying what it should say, I presume it's just gone wrong somehow.

Comment: It still offers to continue without it printing anything, so I guess I'll just do that.

Comment: in fiddle it works : http://jsfiddle.net/6Hmpa/